# How do I show a third button when I press on two buttons in Swift?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have these two buttons and when I press one button and I press another button I want a third button to appear. The code I have currently will show the third button when i press on one button. What I need is to show the third button when both buttons are pressed. How would I do that?

```
//EDIT CODE

if node.name == "firstButton" {

   if firstButtonClicked  {

   thirdButton.hidden = false
   firstButtonClicked = true

   }

}

if node.name == "secondButton" {
   if secondButtonClicked {

   thirdButton.hidden = false 
   secondButtonClicked = true            
}
```

Comment: make a bool check of which buttons have been selected and call a common method in both which checks if both the bool are true -> show the button

Comment: Should I make one bool value or two?

Comment: two. firstButtonClicked and secondButtonClicked

Comment: I updated the code and when I press on either button the third button doesnt show up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var firstClicked = fasle
var secondClicked = false

if node.name == "firstButton" {
   firstClicked = true
   if secondClicked {
       thirdButton.hidden = false
   }
}

if node.name == "secondButton" {
   secondClicked = true 
   if firstClicked {
       thirdButton.hidden = false
   }            
}
```

Comment: It shows the third button when I press on one of the button. I need it so that when i press on both buttons than the third one should appear.

Comment: what do you mean by "press on both buttons"? You mean press them simultanously?? how can you press two button at the same time? use two fingers?

Comment: no press one and then press another. It doesnt matter which one is first or second.

Comment: then this code does exactly that. How could it not work? the logic is reasonable to  me here. Did you set both clicked bool to be false at first place?

Comment: Ohh my bad, I just realized my mistake. It works! Thank you!

Comment: I had the secondClicked and firstClicked backwards.

Comment: @coding22 good to hear, could you accept the answer if it works? thanks :]